# Internal Redirect blog/article.php?id=1 to blog/article/1

Tags: .htaccess

I have a `blog` folder in the `public_html` folder on my server with godaddy.

The .htaccess (in `public_html`) :

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -Multiviews -Indexes   
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /blog/article\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ blog/article/%1? [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/article/([^/.]+)/?$ /blog/article.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

The page takes me to 404 page on my online host with godaddy but it works fine on localhost.

I also tried:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)article\.php\?id=(.*)(&|$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/article.php$  $1/article/%1? [NC,L]
```

but that didn't do anything.

Please help!

Comment: yes. it opens the page on localhost but on godaddy it goes to 404 page. btw. i cleared the cache/cookies (to see if that helps) and tried again still the same result

Comment: .htaccess is not enabled by default on GoDaddy. Ask them to enable it.

Comment: Probably just terminology, but... it is an "external redirect" from "`blog/article.php?id=1` to `blog/article/1`" and an "internal rewrite/redirect" from `blog/article/1` to `blog/article.php?id=1`. Presumably it is primarily the _internal rewrite_ (your last `RewriteRule` in your first code block) that is the problem, since you are already linking to `/blog/article/1` in your page? Try changing the internal rewrite to a temporary redirect (ie. add the `R` flag) - does _anything_ happen?

Comment: Presumably .htaccess must be enabled, for [your other redirects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31620160/htaccess-is-behaving-weird-on-goddady-but-normal-on-localhost) to function?! Do you have any other .htaccess files in your `/blog` directory?

Comment: I'm not sure if order matters in this respect, but try placing the `Options` directive at the very top, before `RewriteEngine`.

Comment: i don't have any other htaccess files anywhere except in the root folder. I will call godaddy and check if it's enabled, although most of the website clearly works as it does some htaccess commands but not others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. For anyone that might run into the same problem, here is the simple solution:

Make sure that your  tag contains the real url.
What I did was, I put the custom url in the tag and godaddy was not recognizing it.

So what I did was

`<a href="blog/article/1">article 1</a>`

instead it should be

`<a href="blog/article.php?id=1">article 1</a>`

That way it will redirect to the custom url correctly.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Actually, you had it correct to begin with! You should include the "pretty" URL in your page links (this is the URL you are publicising), not the "ugly" parameterized URL (in fact, your users should never see this "ugly" URL - that's the whole point of "pretty" user-friendly URLs). By including the "ugly" URL in your links, your users are going to experience an external redirect every time they click your links - which is not desirable! It doesn't make much sense that linking to the "ugly" URL would work, since you are presumably executing the same code anyway?!

Comment: Linking directly to the "custom URL" is the same as redirecting to it - except you don't have to bother with the "redirecting" bit, since you are already there!

Comment: That what I figured too but it won't work on godaddy. This was the only solution that worked for me. Do you have an idea how to fix it the right way?

Comment: Well, the code in your question (the first block) looks correct and should work IMO. I've seen a lot of cases where people have had problems with .htaccess on GoDaddy, however, this may simply be because a lot of people use GoDaddy, since the solutions I've seen have not been anything unusual. Just to clarify, when you click your link to `blog/article.php?id=1` it presumably redirects and you see `example.com/blog/article/1` in the browser's address bar?

Comment: yeah it redirects like you said but the page returns a 404 error